# TinyMCE Editor - how to access custom attributes through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used to have a textarea with classname '.dyskografia' and I was accessing that class in order to paste some content into it.

It used to be like this:

```
$(this.el).find('.dyskografia').html("blah blah blah");
```

When I incorporated TinyMCE Editor, it messed up with my tags and now I suppose this is what I should be reffering to - data-id="Dyskografia":

```
<body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body " data-id="Dyskografia" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false"><p>...</p></body>
```

How can I change my previous code to be pasting "blah blah blah" into the tag with data-id="Dyskografia"?

Comment: You want to insert into the tag or into the editor?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the content of your TinyMCE editor with this:

```
// Sets the HTML contents of the activeEditor editor
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<span>some</span> html');

// Sets the raw contents of the activeEditor editor
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<span>some</span> html', {format : 'raw'});

// Sets the content of a specific editor (my_editor in this example)
tinyMCE.get('my_editor').setContent(data);

// Sets the bbcode contents of the activeEditor editor if the bbcode plugin was added
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('[b]some[/b] html', {format : 'bbcode'});
```

If you are interesting in more information you can read the [documentation](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.setContent)